# MongoDB: Designing a statistics dashboard schema

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm designing a database for statistics dashboard, the data is going to be aggregated from my main system and saved in Mongo.

I'm trying to find the best way to model my Database, the issue i'm having is that users can filter the graphs based on different criteria like (Time Range, Age group, Gender)

This article is very helpful regarding Time range but i'm confused how to mix all the filters together.

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

**For example**

Generate `Total page views per product` graph, the mongo db record should look similar to:

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “page_views”,
  product_id: 1550
  values: {
    0: { 0: 999999, 1: 999999, …, 59: 1000000 },
    1: { 0: 2000000, 1: 2000000, …, 59: 1000000 },
    …,
    58: { 0: 1600000, 1: 1200000, …, 59: 1100000 },
    59: { 0: 1300000, 1: 1400000, …, 59: 1500000 }
  }
}
```

This would work really well if users can only filter Time Range, but then how to organize this if users mix it with Age group or gender

```
{
    timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
    type: “page_views”,
    product_id: 1550
    values: {
        0: { 
            0: {
                total: 999999,
                age_group: {
                    teenagers: 4032932,
                    adults: 432942,
                    ...
                },
                gender: {
                    male: 4239423,
                    female: 4342343
                }

            },
            1: {
                total: 999999,
                age_group: {
                    teenagers: 4032932,
                    adults: 432942,
                    ...
                },
                gender: {
                    male: 4239423,
                    female: 4342343
                }
            },
            ....
            59: {
                total: 999999,
                age_group: {
                    teenagers: 4032932,
                    adults: 432942,
                    ...
                },
                gender: {
                    male: 4239423,
                    female: 4342343
                }
            }
        },
        ....
        59: { 
            0: {
                total: 999999,
                age_group: {
                    teenagers: 4032932,
                    adults: 432942,
                    ...
                },
                gender: {
                    male: 4239423,
                    female: 4342343
                }

            },
            1: {
                total: 999999,
                age_group: {
                    teenagers: 4032932,
                    adults: 432942,
                    ...
                },
                gender: {
                    male: 4239423,
                    female: 4342343
                }
            },
            ....
            59: {
                total: 999999,
                age_group: {
                    teenagers: 4032932,
                    adults: 432942,
                    ...
                },
                gender: {
                    male: 4239423,
                    female: 4342343
                }
            }
        },
    }
}
```

The issue i can see with this, is what if users mix (Age range, Age group and gender) together

Comment: Are you open to a different database other than MongoDB? There is a class of time-series databases https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database that are quite performant with aggregation queries which means you only save raw data and the let the databases do the rest. The added benefit of not storing precomputed aggregates is that you change raw data down the road, e.g. update/revise and see your aggregates reflect it without any inconsistencies.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov thanks for your response. yeah i'm open but not sure which one would be a good choice since stability is a key here InfluxDB looks promising but not sure it's wise to use it at this stage in a production environment since the project is still relatively new and not passed alpha yet, would prefer an open source solution, any suggestion?

Comment: HBase-based systems: OpenTSDB, Bosun (on top of OpenTSDB), and ATSD. The first 2 are FOSS. Disclosure: I work for the company that develops ATSD.

Comment: appreciate your response @SergeiRodionov i will check them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to store aggregate data. It is fundamentally complex to add search criteria to already aggregated data. You will need to make a tradeoff between raw data and aggregated data.

- **More raw data** means easier to mix and match different filter criteria, but also possibly slower runtimes.
- **More aggregated data** means that you need to predefine what criteria it should be possible to filter on.

At the moment you are just discovering this border between raw and pre-computed data, and you will see that you are already down to the smallest possible storage size for the criteria you want. If you want one dimension you might need X amount of storage. If you want two dimensions you might need X^2 amount of storage. Three dimensions needs X^3 and so on.

At some point you might want to consider using a time series-oriented database instead, such as InfluxDB, Splunk or similar. Such databases are optimized for storing and indexing raw log-oriented data.